# While decoding and getting json value i am getting error?

Tags: php, jquery

In productoptions column in database table, I insert the value as shown here:

```
[{"value":["Color","size",""]},{"Color":["Red","Blue","white"],"size":["L","XL"]},{"type":["Dropdown","Checkbox",""]}]
```

After that I got the option values

```
$opt =$value->ProductOptions;
```

Then I decode the json value by  using following

```
$jsonvalue = json_decode($opt);
```

And I get a value like this:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [value] => Array ( [0] => Color [1] => size [2] => ) ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [Color] => Array ( [0] => Red [1] => Blue [2] => white ) [size] => Array ( [0] => L [1] => XL ) ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [type] => Array ( [0] => Dropdown [1] => Checkbox [2] => ) ) )
```

After decoding, I am trying to get particular object (color, size etc)

```
foreach ($jsonvalue as $key => $values) {
  print_r($vales->Color);
}
```

But i am error like below:

> Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$Color

I am get value

```
value => color,size
```

After that in need pass above value dynamically and get

```
color => red,blue,white
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON structure is a bit odd, you have mixed data and structures.

But if you use `print_r($jsonvalue);` you can see how the arrays and objects are laid out, this shows that the `[0]` item has the `value` element, and the `[1]` has the data indicated by the values, so...

One of the items in your `value` element is `""`, this can cause problems so you may want to add a check to ignore empty items.

```
foreach ( $jsonvalue[0]->value as $types ) {
    if ( !empty($types) )   {
        echo $types.PHP_EOL;
        print_r($jsonvalue[1]->{$types});
    }    
}
```

gives you...

```
Color
Array
(
    [0] => Red
    [1] => Blue
    [2] => white
)
size
Array
(
    [0] => L
    [1] => XL
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
foreach ($jsonvalue as $key => $values) {
  print_r($vales->{$key});
}
```

Comment: after using this code i got error code :Message: Undefined property: stdClass::$0

Comment: Try to use array instead of object `$jsonvalue = json_decode($opt);` to `$jsonvalue = json_decode($opt,true);` and `print_r($vales->{$key});` to `print_r($vales[$key]);`